# How can I defined regions like default admin theme (Seven)?

Tags: theming

For example, visit admin/structure/block/manage/search/form/configure
config search block, in "Region settings", can see Seven (administration theme) "Dashboard(sidebar)" selected, but I find Seven Theme's file, there is no region defined as "Dashboard(sidebar)".

So how can I do the same thing as Seven Theme?

Comment: Sorry, but we can't replicate [Theming Guide](https://drupal.org/documentation/theme) here. You need to read articles from [How the Drupal theme system works](https://drupal.org/node/337173) introductory instruction, and then if you will have problems, ask us.

Answer (score 1):

That functionality doesn't come from a theme, it's provided by the core Dashboard module.

The short answer to your question is: copy what the Dashboard module does. To actually do it will require a fair bit of development.

The regions are defined in [`dashboard_dashboard_regions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!dashboard!dashboard.module/function/dashboard_dashboard_regions/7), and are eventually added to the page by [`dashboard_page_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!dashboard!dashboard.module/function/dashboard_page_build/7). The whole process bypasses the usual workflow of defining regions in the theme file.

I'm guessing it's been done like this so that the Dashboard can be used by any admin theme, not just the Seven theme included with core.